# How to refresh the content of ProseMirror/Telerik Blazor wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, telerik, wysiwyg

I'm using Telerik Editor (which is wrapping ProseMirror wysiwyg editor) and have a problem with loading new content into the editor. I have a list of elements which when selected changes the @bind-Value of the component, this works fine while debugging but as soon as I test it on a dedicated server it never updates the text which was set by the first selected item.
The content being passed is correct but the iframe content never changes.

I have tried following the suggestions online which says that one should use "StateHasChanged" after loading the new model, but it doesn't change anything. I also tried nulling the value of the model first and running stateHasChanged again before setting it again. I also tried to copy the value of the model into another variable, but the same problem persists.